# List of AWS services that don’t require a VPC to run

Tags: amazon-web-services

Google failed me again or may be I wasnt too clear in my question. 
Is there an easy way or rather how do we determine what services are VPC bound and what services are non-vpc ? 
For example - EC2, RDS require a VPC setup 
Lambda, S3 are publicly available services and doesn't need a VPC setup.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to know, it may help answer. Is there some limitation or design requirement?

Comment: It's not quite that simple. Lambda, for example, can be deployed in your VPC if you want (it's optional). Some (older) AWS accounts also run EC2-Classic, which means that EC2 and RDS can run outside of VPC. What is your goal here?

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned this in my question. At the moment, we are running non-vpc completely and want to stay that way if possible - not a hard requirement though. So I just want to see what services need a VPC.

Comment: Lambda(VPC optionally), CloudFront, S3, APIGW, SES(messaging services) are top of my mind :)

Comment: Could you plz elaborate `non-vpc completely and want to stay that way if possible`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The basic services that require an Amazon VPC are all **related to Amazon EC2 instances**, such as:

- Amazon RDS
- Amazon EMR
- Amazon Redshift
- Amazon Elasticsearch
- AWS Elastic Beanstalk
- etc

These resources run "on top" of Amazon EC2 and therefore connect to a VPC.

There are also other services that use a VPC, but you would only use them if you are using some of the above services, such as:

- Elastic Load Balancer
- NAT Gateway

So, if you wish to run "completely non-vpc", then avoid services that are "deployed". It means you would use AWS Lambda for compute, probably DynamoDB for database, Amazon S3 for object storage, etc. This is otherwise referred to as going "serverless".