# What resources can reside in Amazon VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm kind of confused on the concept of VPC.

I understand that when I create a EC2 instance(s), it automatically resides in a VPC, as EC2 is an virtual server instance. Actually, I understand how VPC settings work (I read all the official tutorial documents for VPC)!

But what about other services or resources? S3, Lambda, RDS, ... Don't they have to be in a VPC either?

Probably, I don't clearly understand what are VPCs for. Or, I have confusions about other managed services AWS provides. I want to get clear about what can be in VPC and what can't be.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56461741/list-of-aws-services-that-don-t-require-a-vpc-to-run

Comment: @MarkB Nice link, thanks.